# Is angular.io is advance version of angularjs?

Tags: angular

It seems angular.io is completely different in the way of coding than angularJS. Which one do I choose to learn and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular.io is angular (without the js at the end) its also called angularjs 2 or angularjs 3,4 which adds to the confusion

1. Uses typescript, or ES5/ES6
2. Is newer

AngularJS 1.6 (https://angularjs.org/)

1. The original angularjs
2. More popular
3. Has more libraries and frameworks already established for it
4. Uses javascript

I recommend using AngularJS due to its easier learning curve and diverse collection of libraries and community.

Comment: Seriously, nobody recommended learn Cobol, and Pascal, or C++. Angular it's more efficient, robust and easier than Angular js. Furthermore, learn Angularjs no help  learn Angular